# Font Squirrel tumblr implementation / Firefox issue

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

I got @font-face working fine in my tumblr site using the simplest method i.e. uploading the font to static.tumblr.com and reference that as the src, but then realised it didn't work for Firefox.

I know there're a lot of questions about this Firefox @font-face issue and I'm trying to fix this in my tumblr site. I understand the issue and I understand the concept of the fix, but I really don't understand how to actually implement it.

I've read about the Base64 encode solution, and choosing that option in the expert settings of font squirrel, but my problem I don't really understand what to do with the various files it gives you and the exact syntax of the code to get it to work cross-browser.

Would love some help here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with .SVG's order of inclusion being the issue, this post explains a fix.

Comment: Help if i attached the link eh? ^^ this is it